# Pyspark: how to create a new column and match the column's value condition with row value

Tags: python, pyspark

```
date        hos time topwait
19/9/2020   KHW 11:00   5
19/9/2020   CCM 11:00   6
19/9/2020   HHJ 11:00   7
19/9/2020   KHW 12:00   1
19/9/2020   CCM 12:00   2
19/9/2020   HHJ 12:00   4
22/9/2020   KHW 11:00   9
22/9/2020   CCM 11:00   9
22/9/2020   HHJ 11:00   9
22/9/2020   KHW 11:00   4
22/9/2020   CCM 11:00   3
22/9/2020   HHJ 11:00   2
.
.
.
```

I have been given data like shown above and I want to add some new columns to see the 'topwait' at the given time slot of that day. Like the table shown below.

```
date       hos     time topwait 11:00 12:00
19/9/2020   KHW    11:00    5   5   1
19/9/2020   CCM    11:00    6   6   2
19/9/2020   HHJ    11:00    7   7   4
19/9/2020   KHW    12:00    1   5   1
19/9/2020   CCM    12:00    2   6   2
19/9/2020   HHJ    12:00    4   7   4
22/9/2020   KHW    11:00    9   9   4
22/9/2020   CCM    11:00    9   9   3
22/9/2020   HHJ    11:00    9   9   2
22/9/2020   KHW    12:00    4   9   4
22/9/2020   CCM    12:00    3   9   3
22/9/2020   HHJ    12:00    2   9   2
.
.
.
```

I am using pyspark and have tried the code below. But it can only add value when the time slot match the column's condition and other's would have shown null.

`tt = df.withColumn('11:00',when((df.time == '11:00'), df.topwait))`

```
date        hos    time topwait 11:00 12:00
19/9/2020   KHW    11:00    5   5     null
19/9/2020   CCM    11:00    6   6     null
19/9/2020   HHJ    11:00    7   7     null
19/9/2020   KHW    12:00    1   null    1
19/9/2020   CCM    12:00    2   null    2
19/9/2020   HHJ    12:00    4   null    4
22/9/2020   KHW    11:00    9   9     null
22/9/2020   CCM    11:00    9   9     null
22/9/2020   HHJ    11:00    9   9     null
22/9/2020   KHW    12:00    4   null    4
22/9/2020   CCM    12:00    3   null    3
22/9/2020   HHJ    12:00    2   null    2
.
.
.
```

I guess it needs to also condition with the row's date but I have no idea how to condition with row value. Is it possible to achive by using pyspark? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot and join also work.

```
df.join(df.groupBy('date', 'hos').pivot('time').agg(first('topwait').alias('topwait')), ['date', 'hos'], 'left') \
  .show()

+---------+---+-----+-------+-----+-----+
|     date|hos| time|topwait|11:00|12:00|
+---------+---+-----+-------+-----+-----+
|19/9/2020|KHW|11:00|      5|    5|    1|
|19/9/2020|CCM|11:00|      6|    6|    2|
|19/9/2020|HHJ|11:00|      7|    7|    4|
|19/9/2020|KHW|12:00|      1|    5|    1|
|19/9/2020|CCM|12:00|      2|    6|    2|
|19/9/2020|HHJ|12:00|      4|    7|    4|
|22/9/2020|KHW|11:00|      9|    9|    4|
|22/9/2020|CCM|11:00|      9|    9|    3|
|22/9/2020|HHJ|11:00|      9|    9|    2|
|22/9/2020|KHW|12:00|      4|    9|    4|
|22/9/2020|CCM|12:00|      3|    9|    3|
|22/9/2020|HHJ|12:00|      2|    9|    2|
+---------+---+-----+-------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is not a simple matching. With matching it need data from either previous or later hour, for this we need partition/group over `date, hos` and order by `time`. `lag` incase on next hour, `lead` incase of previous hour.

See Below -

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([['19/9/2020','KHW','11:00','5'],
['19/9/2020','CCM','11:00','6'],
['19/9/2020','HHJ','11:00','7'],
['19/9/2020','KHW','12:00','1'],
['19/9/2020','CCM','12:00','2'],
['19/9/2020','HHJ','12:00','4'],
['22/9/2020','KHW','11:00','9'],
['22/9/2020','CCM','11:00','9'],
['22/9/2020','HHJ','11:00','9'],
['22/9/2020','KHW','12:00','4'],
['22/9/2020','CCM','12:00','3'],
['22/9/2020','HHJ','12:00','2']], ['date','hos', 'time', 'topwait'])

spark_df.withColumn('11:00',
                    f.when(
                        spark_df.time == '11:00', 
                        spark_df.topwait
                    ).otherwise(
                        f.lag(spark_df.topwait).over(Window.partitionBy("date", "hos").orderBy("time")))
                    )\
.withColumn('12:00',
                    f.when(
                        spark_df.time == '12:00', 
                        spark_df.topwait
                    ).otherwise(
                        f.lead(spark_df.topwait).over(Window.partitionBy("date", "hos").orderBy("time")))
                    )\
.sort(["date", "time"]).show()   

+---------+---+-----+-------+-----+-----+
|     date|hos| time|topwait|11:00|12:00|
+---------+---+-----+-------+-----+-----+
|19/9/2020|KHW|11:00|      5|    5|    1|
|19/9/2020|CCM|11:00|      6|    6|    2|
|19/9/2020|HHJ|11:00|      7|    7|    4|
|19/9/2020|KHW|12:00|      1|    5|    1|
|19/9/2020|CCM|12:00|      2|    6|    2|
|19/9/2020|HHJ|12:00|      4|    7|    4|
|22/9/2020|HHJ|11:00|      9|    9|    2|
|22/9/2020|KHW|11:00|      9|    9|    4|
|22/9/2020|CCM|11:00|      9|    9|    3|
|22/9/2020|CCM|12:00|      3|    9|    3|
|22/9/2020|KHW|12:00|      4|    9|    4|
|22/9/2020|HHJ|12:00|      2|    9|    2|
+---------+---+-----+-------+-----+-----+
```